# Digital filtering in matlab not giving expected results

Tags: algorithm, matlab, filtering, digital-filter

I'm trying to design and test a simple digital high pass filter in matlab.
I have two scripts: the first one is to design the filter, the second one is the implementation fo the recursion algorithm

1st script: desgn of the filter:

```
s=sym('s');
z=sym('z');
w=sym('w');
p=sym('p');
f=sym('f');
x=sym('x');
Pi=sym('Pi');
Ts=sym('Ts');
vc=sym('vc');

n=2;
Fspb=1/(s^2+sqrt(2)*s+1);   % simple low pass butterworth
Fs=subs(Fspb, s, 2*Pi*vc/s); % tranform to high pass butterworth with vc cutting freq
Fz=subs(Fs, s, 2/Ts*(z-1)/(z+1)); %bilinear transformation
Fp=subs(Fz, z, exp(Ts*p))
Fw=subs(Fp, p, 1i*w);
Ff=subs(Fw, w, 2*Pi*f);

vmax=5000;
vc_val=1000; %1000 Hz
vccont=1/Pi/Ts*tan(Pi*Ts*vc_val);
Ts_val=0.0001
fval=0:0.1:vmax;

pretty(expand(Fz))

[num, den]=numden(Fz);
cn=coeffs(num,z)
cd=coeffs(den,z)
```

it gives me the coefficients (for z) and the frequency response of the filter:

```
cn =     
[ 1, -2, 1]

cd =
[ Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 - 2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc + 1, 2*Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 - 2, Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 + 2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc + 1]
```

[image: filter]

here is the mfilter displayed with the freqz function:

[image: filter]

and my second script, implementing the filter and testing on a simple sinus function:

```
Pi=3.14;
v=500;
Ts=0.0001;
x=0:Ts:100000*Ts;

y=sin(x*2*Pi*v); % sinus, freq=v
figure;
plot(x,y);

%% filter def
vc_val=1; %1000 Hz
vccont=1/Pi/Ts*tan(Pi*Ts*vc_val);

a=Pi^2*Ts^2*vccont^2;
b=sqrt(2)*Pi*Ts*vccont;

%% filtering
yf=zeros(1,size(y,2));

y1=0; y2=0; y3=0; y4=0; x1=0; x2=0; x3=0; x4=0;

for i=3:size(y,2)
     if (i>1)
         y1=yf(i-1);
         x1=xyi-1);
         if (i>2)
             y2=yf(i-2);
             x2=y(i-2);
         end
     end
    yf(i)=1/(a-b+1)*(-(2*a-2)*y1-(a+b+1)*y2+y(i)-2*x1+x2);
end

figure;
plot(x,yf);
```

But it doesn't give me the result i was expecting (left: the original sinus, right: the filtered result at 1/2 of the cutting frequency):

[image: results]

I checked that my filter is stable, I can't see what the problem may be. Have you got any hint?

thanks!

Comment: Your second script only gives 1 `b` coefficient. Should you not have 3?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by only one `b` coefficient? `b` is just equal to `2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc`, it is not a coefficient of the denominator, which are `a-b+1`, `2a-2` and `a+b+1`

Comment: Can you try using the filter command? That will narrow down the issue to either the filter function or your filter coeffcients. Also run freqz or fvtool with your filter coefficients to check your response.

Comment: Thanks! When using the filter function, i get similar results than with with my algorhythm, so i guess the problem comes from the filter design.
I updated the question with the result of freqz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, which is that the **`numden()` function of matlab doesn't give the right numerators and denominators**. thanks to the people who took time to help me!

the following code gives a wrong result:

```
z=sym('z');
Pi=sym('Pi');
Ts=sym('Ts');
vc=sym('vc');

Fz=1/((Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2)/(z^2 - 2*z + 1) + (2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc)/(z - 1) + (2*Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2*z)/(z^2 - 2*z + 1) + (Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2*z^2)/(z^2 - 2*z + 1) + (2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc*z)/(z - 1) + 1)

[num, den]=numden(Fz);
cn=coeffs(num,z)
cd=coeffs(den,z)
```

matlab gives the coefficients:

> cn =
>
> [ 1, -2, 1]
>
> cd =
>
> [ Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 - 2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc + 1, 2*Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 - 2, Pi^2*Ts^2*vc^2 + 2^(1/2)*Pi*Ts*vc + 1]

which are obvisoulsy wrong

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify whether numden had a bug or your use is not supported?

Comment: Well, it's difficult for me to say if it's a bug or if i don't use it as intended... 
I updated my response to give a simple code example that show wrong coefficients with numdem. i'm using matlab 2011b

Comment: Why do you say those coefficients are wrong or that `numden` isn't working? Seems correct to me. `Fz` as written isn't in a standard form where the numerator and denominator are polynomials in `z`. Try `pretty(simplify(Fz))`. This is the form that `numden` operates on and where the coefficients come from.

Comment: pretty(simplify(Fz)) isn't giving me the correct formula either

Answer (score 1):

The result is probably correct. Your sine wave frequency is 500 and your sampling frequency is 10000. Your normalized frequency is 500/10000=0.05 which is filtered. So you see the highly attenuated output. You should increase your sine wave frequency and see whether you get your sine wave back after filtering.